# Get properties of empty linq statement

Tags: linq, reflection, datatable

Is there a way of looping through the properties of the underlining result of the linq statement when the linq statement contains no elements?

I would like to create a DataTable and add the individual properties as columns, but it seems this can only be done when the linq statement contains items. Please see my current code below

```
private static void GetProperties<T>(IEnumerable<T> query) 
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    PropertyInfo[] queryInfo = null;

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        if (queryInfo == null) 
        {
            queryInfo = item.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var info in queryInfo)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(info.Name);
            }
        }

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in queryInfo)
        {
            dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Desired code, or something similar:

```
private static void GetProperties<T>(IEnumerable<T> query) 
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    PropertyInfo[] queryInfo = null;

    queryInfo = query.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var info in queryInfo)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(info.Name);
    }

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in queryInfo)
        {
            dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

I would always like the DataTable to contain the columns, even if the linq statement contains no items.

I am open to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* all you're looking for it:

```
PropertyInfo[] queryInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties();
```

In other words, get the properties from the generic type argument rather than for a particular *instance* of that type.